# Linear models : Given the fact that both the models perform equally well on the test data set, which one would you prefer and why?

Tags: python, linear-regression

Consider two linear models:
L1: y = 39.76x + 32.648628
And
L2: y = 43.2x + 19.8
Given the fact that both the models perform equally well on the test data set, which one would you prefer and why?

Comment: How come 19.8 is so well rounded?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with the second one, just because the numbers in the second one are rounded more, and if they still do equally well, the extra digits in the first one are unnecessary and just make it look worse.

(As a side note, this question doesn't seem related to programming so you may want to post it in a different community.)